# OpenId Endpoint for PayPal Authentication

Tags: oauth, paypal, openid

I've been searching the docs and googling like a maniac, but I can't find the sandbox openid endpoint/identifier for paypals sandbox.  I've got the productive url, https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/server, but to use it I need an approved app.
I just want to test the flow, before I go through the hastle of creating an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer from PayPal: The OpenId/Oauth stuff is currenlty in a closed beta.